# Getting a "Cannot Read That as a Zip File" Exception while trying to get a stream from an Inner Zip File (a Zip within another Zip)

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

In C#, I'm using the **DotNetZip**
I have a zip called "innerZip.zip" which contains some data,
and another zip called "outerZip.zip" which contains the innerZip.
why am i doing it like this ?
well, when setting the password, the password actually applies to individual entries that are added to the archive and not the whole archive, by using this inner/outer combo,
I could set a pass to the whole inner zip because it's an entry of the outer one.

Problem is, well, code speaks better than normal words:

```
ZipFile outerZip = ZipFile.Read("outerZip.zip");
outerZip.Password = "VeXe";
Stream innerStream = outerZip["innerZip.zip"].OpenReader();
ZipFile innerZip = ZipFile.Read(innerStream); // I'm getting the exception here.
innerZip["Songs\\IronMaiden"].Extract(tempLocation);
```

why am I getting that exception ?
the inner file is a zip file, so i shouldn't be getting that exception right ?
is there a way to get around this or I just have to extract the inner one from the outer, and then access it ?

Thanx in advance ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exception occurs because the `CrcCalculatorStream` stream that `OpenReader` creates is not seekable, and `ZipFile.Read(Stream)` tries to seek while opening the zip file.

The nature of zip compression prevents seeking to a location in the zipped content, the content must be decompressed in order.

One way around this would be to extract the inner zip file to a `MemoryStream` and then load that via `ZipFile.Read`.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
outerZip["innerZip.zip"].Extract(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
ZipFile innerZip = ZipFile.Read(ms);
innerZip["Songs\\IronMaiden"].Extract(tempLocation);
```

Comment: I know this post is a bit dated. But thank you for the tip! It saved a colleague of mine hours of fiddling! +1