# dotnetzip - Cannot read that as a ZipFile / Bad signature at position 0x00000000

Tags: c#, unzip, dotnetzip

I want to unzip a rar file with DotNetZip that have just one entry

```
 using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFilePath))//Get exception here
  {
    foreach (ZipEntry ex in zip)
    ex.Extract(Path.GetDirectoryName(zipFilePath), ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
   }
```

It's unzipe on a file with 5KB
but gets me error on e file with 45MB size:

> Cannot read that as a ZipFile   in inner exceptin:
>       Bad signature (0x21726152) at position  0x00000000

StackTrace:

> at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.ReadIntoInstance(ZipFile zf)
>   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(String fileName, TextWriter
>   statusMessageWriter, Encoding encoding, EventHandler`1 readProgress)
>   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(String fileName)    at
>   ExtractFile(String
>   zipFilePath, String tempDirectoryPath) in D:\Projects\MainForm.cs:line
>   212

I also tried to read from MemoryStream, a Suggestion that comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857913/getting-a-cannot-read-that-as-a-zip-file-exception-while-trying-to-get-a-strea)

but it doesn't work.

Comment: rar file is NOT a zip file. Are you sure `ZipFile` will also support rar file?

Comment: I'm sure DotNetZip library support it.

Comment: Read the [DotNetZip FAQ](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). It cannot create or read RAR files.

Comment: @Rick, thank you so much. right is with you.